# Linux mint ddns and iptables ssh,ftp connect

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, iptables, dynamic-dns

I have a 3g usb modem connected via usb to the PC. Dynamic ip. I need to connect to this PC as a server via ssh or ftp.
As I've read on the Internet, I need:

1. Configure Dynu Dns, in order to track the change of ip on the PC. I made all the necessary settings and Dynu Dns tracks the external dynamic ip.
2. Skip ports for ssh and ftp.

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 11.11.11.11 --dport 22
>    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:22
>
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 11.11.11.11:22

Anyway, I can not connect remotely to this PC.